# Ubuntu 10.10: Python 2.5 for App Engine and pygtk

Tags: ubuntu, python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I need Python 2.5 for Google App Engine. I downloaded and compiled Python 2.5.5 from sources, set it as default python, but now when I try to run Ubuntu Software Center I get:

```
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

ReInstalling python-gtk2 does not help. What is the easiest and preferred way to get Python 2.5 on Ubuntu 10.10 for App Engine development?

Comment: The issue is because when you run python2.5 it looks in python2.5's site-packages for python modules. You should check out virtualenv: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: I understand this, but I don't know how virtualenv can help me manage different versions of Python (AFAIK it does not do this). The problem is that I have to compile python (2.5) with right params and install all packages required by Ubuntu (I did not succeed in this). Fortunately GAE now supports Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Python 2.5 Packages for Ubuntu 10.10 here:

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes